# How to reorganise these columns and rows in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose we have the following data frame

```
value_1 value_2 label_1 label_2
3       2       Good    Bad 
4       3       Good    Bad
5       3       Good    Bad
```

I want to rearrange the data so that it looks like this:

```
value label
3     Good
4     Good
5     Good
2     Bad
3     Bad
3     Bad
```

I.e. value_1 corresponds to the label_1 column, and value_2 corresponds to the label_2 column

Seems like a simple thing but I can't find a solution. I thought `bind_rows()` would work from `dplyr`, but this only seems to work on two data sets. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c('.value','num'), names_pattern = '(.*)_(\\d)') %>% 
    select(-1) %>% arrange(desc(label))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  value label
  <dbl> <chr>
1     3 Good 
2     4 Good 
3     5 Good 
4     2 Bad  
5     3 Bad  
6     3 Bad
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  value_1 value_2 label_1 label_2
    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
1       3       2 Good    Bad    
2       4       3 Good    Bad    
3       5       3 Good    Bad
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution. The approach is to "lengthen" the value and label columns separately and then bind. Note that this solution doesn't "link" `value_1` with `label_1` inherently, but rather relies on the ordering being correct when doing `bind_cosl()`

```
values <- df %>%
  select(starts_with("value"))
labels <- df %>%
  select(starts_with("label"))

out <- bind_cols(values %>% 
                   pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
                   select(value), 
                 labels %>% 
                   pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
                   select(value)) %>%
  rename(value = `value...1`,
         label = `value...2`) %>%
  arrange(desc(label))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  value label
  <dbl> <chr>
1     3 good 
2     4 good 
3     5 good 
4     2 bad  
5     3 bad  
6     3 bad
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the extremely elegant answer from Karthik S, here's another approach that pulls the `data.frame` into two parts and fixes the names to that `dplyr::bind_rows` will allow you to bind them. Probably a worse solution but it might have advantages in some scenarios and since you asked for `bind_rows` here it is...

```r
bind_rows(
  df %>%  select(value = 1, label = 3),
  df %>%  select (value = 2, label = 4)
)

#   value label
# 1     3  Good
# 2     4  Good
# 3     5  Good
# 4     2   Bad
# 5     3   Bad
# 6     3   Bad
```